# Who invented directional damage indicator

Tags: first-person-shooter

Just out of curiosity. I'm talking about this sort of thing:
[image: frontal damage indicator]

In fact Half-Life is the earliest game I can think of that had them. Surely they'd been invented before? Or is it yet another seldom praised innovative feature of Half-Life? Quake 2, e.g., didn't use them and came out a year earlier, I know little of the more obscure FPS games of the time.

I can't imagine there being a definitive answer so the winner's gonna be the earliest game you can remember that does have directional damage indicator.

Comment: Unfortunately, this falls under game identification by feature, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Wolfenstein 3D and Doom used the direction the head icon is looking in the status bar to show which direction damage was coming from, although that only told you left/right not front/back.